# JDBC URL for Oracle XA client

Tags: oracle, url, jdbc

Using the JDBC driver oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource, what is the correct format of the JDBC URL? The thin format of

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port:sid
```

does not work. WebSphere is reporting that the given url (which is otherwise correct) is invalid.

```
The test connection operation failed for data source Oracle MyDB (XA) on 
server nodeagent at node MY_node with the following exception: 
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid Oracle URL specifiedDSRA0010E: SQL State = 99999, 
Error Code = 17,067. View JVM logs for further details.
```

There is nothing in the JVM logs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whether you use a XA Driver or not, the JDBC connection string is the same (and the format of your question is correct).

Comment: I thought so, but the error message was saying otherwise. That there was no JVM logging at all was the thing that made me think WAS was in a bad state...

Answer (score 5):

For me the issue resolved by adding alias name, username and password in JAAS - J2C authentication data. And also selecting this entry as Component-managed authentication alias.

Answer (score 3):

In case this happens to anyone else. The problem went away after restarting websphere.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the problem went away when I change the authentication property of the jdbc resource reference from `Authentication=Application` to `Authentication=Container`

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. Dont know about simple deployments, but on a two nodes cluster, I restarted the first node, and the connection started working on it (not on the second). Restarted the second node, and the connection started working there too.

So just restart the nodes (I also restarted the nodeAgents, but i don't know if it's necessary).

Answer (score 0):

if you are doing using wsadmin command then you need to stop manager,stop node,start manager, sync node and then start node (I mean full sync). Hopefully this will resolve the issue. I dont know why but this resolves my issue.